# How do I get a value from the default constructor to the console?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to output data from the default constructor, that is, 0, 0 and 0. The compiler swears if the call constructor is not initialized when calling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
public:
    Date() : day(0), month(0), year(0) {}
    Date(unsigned d, unsigned m, unsigned y) : day(d), month(m), year(y) {}
    friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Date&);
private:
    unsigned day, month, year;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.day << '/' << dt.month << '/' << dt.year;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Date dt(19, 7, 2003); //works
    // Date dt(); // it does not allow, I want to output 0 0 0
    std::cout << dt << std::endl;
    return 0;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Or it seems to me that I don't understand at all what the default constructor is for

```
// unresolved external symbol "class Date __cdecl dt(void)" (?dt@@YA?AVDate@@XZ) referenced in function _main
// 1 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initialize a class on the stack with the default constructor you leave off the parenthesis,

```
Date dt;
std::cout << dt << std::endl;
return 0;
```

also, the `std::cin.get()` will never be run as it's after the `return 0;`

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) where `Date dt();` is parsed as a function declaration. This is why you see an unresolved symbol as the function `dt` is never given a body.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
public:
    Date() : day(0), month(0), year(0) {}
    Date(unsigned d, unsigned m, unsigned y) : day(d), month(m), year(y) {}
    friend inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Date&);
private:
    unsigned day, month, year;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.day << '/' << dt.month << '/' << dt.year;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Date dt;
    std::cout << dt << std::endl;
    return 0;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: This is merely a vexing parse. the MOST vexing parse has a parameter involved that's also interpreted as a function. The classic example looks something like `A a( A() );`

Comment: @user4581301 huh wonder how I never ran into that before